# Blazor optional route parameters

Tags: blazor

Create new blazor project with `dotnet new blazor`. Modify `Index.cshtml`:

```cs
@page "/"
@page "/{Id}"

<h1>Id = @Id</h1>

<p><a href="/">Without Id</a></p>
<p><a href="/15">With Id = 15</a></p>

@functions {
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Run application.

When I click `With Id = 15` link, everything works as expected - url has changed, parameter `{Id}` is assigned to value `Id`, all good.

But when I click `Without Id` link after that, url has changed, but my Id stays the same - equal 15.

Why my value didn't change? What am I missing here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Tried a default empty string value on the Param?

Comment: @HenkHolterman there is nothing in console. The page is not loading - there are no requests to server when I click links. This is blazor.

Comment: @MisterMagoo default empty string didn't helped.

Comment: This answer on a similar question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568084/navlink-updating-url-but-does-not-reloading-page-in-blazor/69237268#69237268

Answer (score 18):

Optional route parameters are supported [as of ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters).

For example:

```
@page "/RouteParameter/{text?}"

<h1>Blazor is @Text!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = Text ?? "fantastic";
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Since .NET 8 it is possible to wirte the assignment `Text ??= "fantastic"`

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is by design. 
Note that a changed url does not imply that the current page has changed. The following JavaScript function performs the internal navigation which changes the url:

```js
function performInternalNavigation(absoluteInternalHref: string) {
  history.pushState(null, /* ignored title */ '', absoluteInternalHref);
  handleInternalNavigation();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/93127b39e824181d4f9b1a62b6fc8d10c481e2c8/src/Components/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.JS/src/Services/UriHelper.ts

Calling history.pushState causes the URL bar to display ".../15", but won't cause the browser to load the new url, or rather cause Blazor to recreate the Index component. Blazor does not recreate a component if only the URL parameters change. Since you are already on the Index page, clicking on the link "Without Id", does not cause the Index Component to re-render. The current Component instance is reused instead, but alas this instance component has its parameter property set to the value of 15, and it is not overwritten by the AssignToProperties method which "Iterates through the ParameterCollection, assigning each parameter to a property of the same name on target." But the ParameterCollection does not contain an Id parameter; recall that this occurs after you hit the "Without Id". The end result, again, is having the parameter property Id containing the value 15.
Source: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/29f925852b0a5e81e82780e0c1c32b486f7c3be6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor/Components/ParameterCollectionExtensions.cs

Workarounds to solve this issue:

1. Override the SetParameters method like this:

```cs
public override void SetParameters(ParameterCollection parameters)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Id")))
   {
      Id = null;
   }
   base.SetParameters(parameters);
}
```

2. Implement custom routing logic by subclassing Router

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. This really explains the problem. As a workaround I already register for `OnLocationChanged` and apply my custom logic there, but this seems like a hack, not a proper logic. Something similar to: https://learn-blazor.com/pages/router/#accessing-query-parameters Don't you think, that during iteration through ParameterCollection, unassigned parameters should be cleared? Imho this is what users are expecting...

Comment: Every solution may seem like a hack, including your current solution. As I've said above, this behavior is by design. A couple of attempts were made to solve this seemingly faulty design, but none has succeeded yet. The condition to change this design, according to Steve Sanderson, should be a design that can be achieved without any extra perf cost, and without resorting to further reflection... Can you do it

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
@page "/"
@page "/{Id:string}"

<h1>Id = @Id</h1>

<p><NavLink href="/">Without Id</NavLink></p>
<p><NavLink href="/15">With Id = 15</NavLink></p>

@code{
  [Parameter]
  public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

**I hope your problem is solved**

Answer (score 1):

Optional route parameter example with route constraint:

```
@page "/user/{Id:int}/{Option:bool?}"

<p>
    Id: @Id
</p>

<p>
    Option: @Option
</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Option { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints

A few other examples of what works and what does not work:

```
/product/5 - Works
/product/5/2 - Works

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId:int?}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int? TabId { get; set; }
}

/product/5 - Works
/product/5/2 - Works but needs to be manually converted

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId?}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string TabId { get; set; }
}

/product/5 - Works
/product/5/2 - System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId?}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int? TabId { get; set; }
}

/product/5 - Sorry, there's nothing at this address.
/product/5/2 - System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Project.Client.Pages.ProductDetails' does not have a property matching the name 'TabId?'.

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId?:int}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int? TabId { get; set; }
}

/product/5 - System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Project.Client.Pages.ProductDetails' does not have a property matching the name 'TabId?'.
/product/5/2 - System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Project.Client.Pages.ProductDetails' does not have a property matching the name 'TabId?'.

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId?:int?}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int? TabId { get; set; }
}

/product/5 - Sorry, there's nothing at this address.
/product/5/2 - System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Project.Client.Pages.ProductDetails' does not have a property matching the name 'TabId?'.

@page "/product/{Id:int}/{TabId?:int}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int TabId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to remove the first route. It lets the Router ignore your (missing) parameter.  And then make Id optional with a `?` :

```
@page "/" -- remove this line
@page "/{Id?}"
```

Now something will always be assigned to `Id`, null when it's not there.

Comment: This is just simplest example I could create. My real case scenario is: I'm on page `clients/1234` with client's details, and I have left navigation menu item with <a href="clients"> link. So when I click my left menu link, the page is not refreshing.

Comment: I gathered that, but the reasoning stays: You still go to the clients page and that is still looking at 1234 ....  What kins of refresh did you have in mind, and why not make a /clients and a /clients/details/id ?

Comment: Because /clients is basically just search box, when /clients/id is the same search box + client's details. I didn't want to create two separate pages, and just add `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) { // show details }` element.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is just to set Id to null.  The "if" is not required.

```
public override void SetParameters(ParameterCollection parameters)
{
    Id = null;
    return base.SetParameters(ParametersCollection parameters)
}
```

Or the more current async equivalent