# NavLink updating URL but does not reloading page in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a ProjectBase.razor page that is used to create, view & edit projects.  The following routes all take you to this page:

```
/project/view/{projNum}
/project/create/
/project/edit/{projNum}
```

I also have a Navlink in my navigation menu that allows you to create a new project:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Project/Create" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" >
    <span aria-hidden="true">New Project</span>
</NavLink>
```

If I click on that link while on the view/edit features of the same page, the URL changes to "/Project/Create," but the page itself doesn't refresh or reload.  Is there a way to force this through the NavLink?  Or do I need to add an OnClick function to do this?

Comment: You don't provide enough information, so it's hard to locate the issue. However, the routing does not take place. First off, the href attribute of the NavLink component should be href="project/create", without initial "/". Did you define public parameter properties for your parameters ? if your component is named ProjectBase, it should appear in the route templates as projectbase and not as project...

Comment: To confirm my understanding: If you enter those URLs into the browser, the page loads correct? It's just when you try to go to those links by clicking on a NavLink, that the page doesn't load? (but the URL changes?)

Comment: Kyle, that is correct!  And it's only when it's navigating within the same page. If I was on a completely different Razor page, it will navigate & load just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [refresh Blazor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539158/refresh-blazor-page)

Answer (score 37):

Create and use the OnParametersSetAsync task in your code block for the page.  This event will fire when parameters change.

```
@code
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
// This event will fire when the parameters change
// Put your code here.  

}
```

Comment: Just including the OnParametersSetAsync() method does not actually solve the problem. When you write "Put your code here", exactly what is your suggestion in terms of code that solves OPs question?

Comment: The OP wasn't very specific about the parameters either.  With Blazor, if you're navigating to a page and passing parameters, the page won't refresh if you simply navigate back to the same base URL that uses OnInitSetAsync in the code block as the page initialization - even if the parameters are different.  This code block fires just once upon initial load - hence why navigating back there once already loaded once does not refresh the pgae.  On the other hand, if OnParametersSetAsync() is used, this will fire every time parameters are passed to the page, forcing a page re-load.

Comment: No, this is not correct. OnParametersSetAsync() will not force a reload whenever a parameter is passed to the page. It will force a reload when the passed in parameter is _different_ compared to what was previously passed in. So if your parameter is an int, and you use a NavLink to get to your page, that int will default to 0 because that's what ints do. If you then click the same NavLink again, that int will still be 0, and you won't get a page reload. In other words: you'd have to notify the framework that the parameter is now not 0. The question is how. The answer will solve OPs question.

Comment: Great answer! In fact you should call this event in your parent component not in the child.

Comment: Linus is correct that it won't work if the parameter is the same. I overcame this by setting the id parameter once I persisted the data. i.e. NavLink is "myapp" which defaults to id=0. Once the page saves the object, I set parameter id=newIdFromDatabase and the OnParametersSetAsync triggers.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my case where users have links to other users. I changed my user Id in the navlink in my case, then did a new get on my user and associated lists, and everything refreshed appropriately for me. Something I'm doing on when I'm calling the create page, is setting the Id parameter to 0, null or string.empty depending on your schema, letting the DB assign the Id when I do a Create on the DB.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, using something like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager` and its NavigateTo function with forceLoad set to true will accomplish what you're looking for.

Of course yes, this will require you to set up an onclick function, but this is the way I ended up accomplishing something similar for a site-wide search page which never technically had its URL change outside of the query string search value I was passing it.

That being said, there may be a decent way of doing it with only NavLinks. I'll update my answer when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: Using forceLoad works for most of my scenarios, but I am curious the approach you would take for NavLinks. Hope you have bandwidth to come back and answer! :)

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering what the code for this answer looks like:
`NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/your/route", true);`

Answer (score 7):

In my component I had already overridden `OnInitializedAsync` in order to make an API call to get my data.

My solution looks like this:

```
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
           // Make your API call or whatever else you use to initialize your component here
        }

        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case you have to make below changes as mention by Rod Weir, I am just extending the answer.

```
 /project/view/{projNum}
 /project/create/
 /project/edit/{projNum}
```

For above query parameter you have to define [Parameter] in your code.

```
[Parameter]
public string projNum {get;set;}
```

Then add method

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{

  var projectDetail = await getProjectDetails(projNum); // ProgNum will change as it get changes in url, you don't have to do anything extra here.
}
```

Force page to reload will land you in some other problems, it will get the correct result but the page behavior will change. There are other components on the page like header/left Nav/ etc these will not changes if they are dynamic. It will force you to make changes and hanlde force reload in all the components. Also user experience is affected.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. Solution I have is...

Create new page

```
@page "/project/create/"
<ProjectBase></ProjectBase>
```

That's it! remove `@page` directive for(`/project/create/`) from `ProjectBase` page

Everything will work as expected... now do it for all pages you have.

Comment: Because of the design of Blazor, this is the ideal solution in my opinion.

Comment: For us Blazor noobs, I assume we create a page with any name, e.g. ProjectBaseXyz.razor with the contents as listed above.

Answer (score 1):

That is by design.The page itself doesn't refresh or reload because the `<NavLink>` does not send request to the server (F12 to check) and it redirect to the same page on the client, so nothing updates.

If you enter those URLs in the browser,they will send requests and then refresh page.

A workaround is that you could display different content based on the current route.

```
@page "/project/view/{projNum}"
@page "/project/create/"
@page "/project/edit/{projNum}"
@using Models
<h3>ProjectBase</h3>

@if (projNum == null)
{
<EditForm Model="@createModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="createModel.Name" />

    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</EditForm>
}
else
{


<EditForm Model="@exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
}
@code {


    [Parameter]
    public string projNum { get; set; }

    private ExampleModel createModel = new ExampleModel();
    private ExampleModel exampleModel = new ExampleModel();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        exampleModel.Name = projNum;
    }



    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        //your logic
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }
}
```