# refresh Blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

In the **Blazer Server Side project with .NET 6,** I am on the following page:

[https: //localhost: 7252/Product/a3620f82-7cba-473c-9273-1cf300a181eb](https://localhost:7252/Product/a3620f82-7cba-473c-9273-1cf300a181ec)

I have a **NavLink** on this page that points to the exact same URL above. But when I click on the method, the page does not show any reaction and does not refresh or update. What should I do?

Sample my codes:

```
@page "/Product/{Id:guid}"
@using Application.ProductGalleries.Queries
@using Application.Products.Queries
@using ViewModels.ProductVariants
@using ViewModels.ProductVariantsDetails
@using ViewModels.Products
<div class="col-12 px-0">
                        <h1>
                            <NavLink href="@($"/Product/a3620f82-7cba-473c-9273-1cf300a181eb")">@Model.ProductName</NavLink>
                            </h1>
                        <p>دسته بندی : @Model.CategoryName<span> برند: @Model.BrandName</span></p>
                        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><NavLink href="/">صفحه نخست</NavLink></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><NavLink href="/Products">@Model.CategoryName</NavLink></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@Model.BrandName</li>
                            </ol>
                        </nav>
                    </div>


@code {
[Parameter]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    return base.ShouldRender();
}
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
}

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    base.OnParametersSet();
}

public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
}
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var request = new GetProductByIdQuery() { ProductId = Id };

    var product = await Mediator.Send(request: request);
    if (product.Value != null)
    {
        Model = product.Value;
        GalleryModel = await GetGallery();

    }
}
}
```

During the *search*, if the user has searched for bananas and is on the search page and wants to search for bananas again, the page will not show any reaction.
I went through all the life cycle overrides to see where it was going but it didn't react.

I also thought of using **StateHasChanged ()**. But my code is a **NavLink** and where should I put this code when the project does not enter the life cycle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You actually need to NavigateTo your current Uri with force load. I use simple extension method for this

```
public static void ReloadPage(this NavigationManager manager)
{
     manager.NavigateTo(manager.Uri, true);
}
```

Comment: should this not be also set "replace" true to replace current page with a new one.

Comment: Does this reload the whole Web assembly in the background?

Answer (score 10):

**Try following code:**

```
@code {

    void NevigateToYourUrl()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("YourPagePath");
    }
}
```

**and also you need to inject NavigationManager as follow:**

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
```

**Try:**

```
<a href="" @onclick="@NevigateToYourUrl" @onclick:preventDefault />
```

Comment: My link is NavLink.
<NavLink href="@($"/Product/a3620f82-7cba-473c-9273-1cf300a181eb")">@Model.ProductName</NavLink>

Comment: try:   @MrJahanbin
` <a href="" @onclick="@NevigateToYourUrl" @onclick:preventDefault />`

Comment: Close. Make it `@onclick="() => NevigateToYourUrl("3620f82-7cba-473c-9273-1cf300a181eb")"`

Answer (score 6):

Building on AliNajafZadeh's answer:

```razor
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

...

<a href="" @onclick="@NevigateToYourUrl" @onclick:preventDefault />

...

@code
{
    void NevigateToYourUrl()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("YourPagePath", true);
    }
}
```

Setting the second parameter to true bypasses client-side routing and forces the browser to load the new page from the server.

[relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.navigateto?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to avoid the overridden `NavigateTo` with `forceLoad` set to true due to reloading the session and flickering the page.

The solution was simply an empty page that took a url as a parameter while immediately redirecting. This means it also works when reloading the current page. The trick is to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` when setting the parameter.

**ForceLoader.razor**

```
@page "/forceloader/{navigationUrl}"

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string navigationUrl { get; set; }


    [Inject] private NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo(navigationUrl);
    }

}
```

**Implementation**

```
_navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/forceloader/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(navigationUrl)}");
```

The only caveat I can think of is history control. After using the `ForceLoader` you would need to call `javascript:history.go(-2)` instead of `javascript:history.back()`.

Comment: This is a nice idea, especially in the context of a Blazor hybrid app, where the `forceLoad` has drawbacks like showing the startup screen and recreation of scoped services. With the `replace` parameter set to true, the browser history can even be kept intact `_navigationManager.NavigateTo(navigationUrl, false, true)`. I think one should better use `OnParametersSet()` instead of `OnInitialized()`.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what "During the *search*" means - you haven't shown the *search* - I would say using a NavLink to refresh the current page is the wrong choice - use a button to perform an action that doesn't change the current location.

However, if you really must use a NavLink, just add an `@onclick` handler to it that calls your data load method.

```html
<NavLink href=@($"/Product/{Id}") @onclick=GetProductData>@Model.ProductName</NavLink>
```

```cs
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await GetProductData();
}

protected async Task GetProductData()
{
  var request = new GetProductByIdQuery() { ProductId = Id };

  var product = await Mediator.Send(request: request);
  if (product.Value != null)
  {
      Model = product.Value;
      GalleryModel = await GetGallery();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this code:

```
_navigationManager.Refresh();
```

And insert this on the top of the page

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
```