# MudBlazor link - reload data on same page

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I've a MudBlazor link element like this:

```
<MudNavLink Href="/orders" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">Orders</MudNavLink>
```

This works fine, but when I'm on the exact same page as the link Href and link the link, it does not navigate. I would like it to force a reload making my page able to reload the data.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [refresh Blazor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539158/refresh-blazor-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ForceLoad` parameter. Take a look at the [MudNavLink API](https://mudblazor.com/api/navlink#properties) for details.

You would want that parameter to be set to true only when on the same page.

```xml
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<MudNavLink Href="/orders" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix"

ForceLoad="NavManager.Uri.Contains("orders")" >

Orders
</MudNavLink>
```

Keep in mind that force-loading means that the entire app will be reloaded, not just the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that does not work. Even setting `ForceLoad="true"` does not work. When clicking the `MudNavLink` of the active page, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add Navigation.Refresh(true) to OnClick event.
This is how I solved for a MudLink

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<MudLink Href="@string.Format("{0}/{1}",UrlCuentaMovimiento,context.Item.bco_movimiento)" OnClick="()=>Navigation.Refresh(true)">@context.Item.bco_movimiento_num</MudLink>
```