i have a blazor app for factory layout and i want to make the functionality of reloading every 15 seconds but it doesn't work
i've tried PeriodicTimer and jsinterop but both doesn't achieve the desired behaviour
here's my @code block that outputs no errors, exception nor the expected bahaviour
@code {
public List<Station> Stations = new List<Station>();
private List<Connection> Connections = new List<Connection>();
private List<CurvedConnection> CurvedConnections = new List<CurvedConnection>();
private List<string> LineElements = new List<string>();
private PeriodicTimer periodicTimer;
private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
private bool isInitialized = false;


protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    SetupInitialStations();
    UpdateConnections();
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        isInitialized = true;
        periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

        while (await periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(_cts.Token))
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("reloadPage");
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Periodic work done", currentTime);
        }
    }

public void Dispose()
{
    _cts.Cancel();
    periodicTimer?.Dispose();
}}


Elaborate on "[not] the expected bahaviour". Does it show the initial page?  Anything shown in the Console?

InvokeVoidAsync("reloadPage") - what exactly are you doing here?  Show some details/info for the markup and the JS.

@HenkHolterman it does actually nothing, not an exception, not a log, not a thing.
for testing purposes i've changed the reload function to a simple alert function and still not working, how to validate that the jsinterop is actually running? thanks in advance

function reloadPage() {
window.location.reload();
}
@HenkHolterman

what i do in this case is navigate to an empty page passing a parameter of the razor page name to go back to. This triggers the reload of a page.    So inject the Navigation Manager at the top of the page :
@inject NavigationManager nav;
then in your code where you want the reload to happen:
nav.NavigateTo("/EmptyPage?firstPage");
see this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539158/refresh-blazor-page

Your Timer will tick only once.  Any particular reason to use JS instead of something like  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63060065/60761

what i do in this case is navigate to an empty page passing a parameter of the razor page name to go back to. This triggers the reload of a page.    So inject the Navigation Manager at the top of the page :
@inject NavigationManager nav;

then in your code where you want the reload to happen:
 nav.NavigateTo("/EmptyPage?firstPage");

EmptyPage.razor is only this:
 @page "/EmptyPage/{GoToPage}"
 @inject NavigationManager nav;

    @code
    {
        [Parameter] public string GoToPage { get; set; }
    
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
    
            nav.NavigateTo($"/{GoToPage}");
        }
    
    }

see this issue:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539158/refresh-blazor-page]
